# Error Installing dependencies on Swanky project init

Tags: ink, astar

I recently update `Swanky Suite` latest version `@astar-network/swanky-cli/0.2.1 darwin-x64 node-v16.14.0`. I create new project with `swanky init my_project` but throws `Error Installing dependencies`. Is there any issue in latest release? or I am doing something wrong? I also compile the project and error `Error: command compile not found`.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue. Upgrade your NodeJS version to `v18.10.0`.

You can also look at [the pull request](https://github.com/AstarNetwork/swanky-cli/pull/23)

Comment: thanks for answer, after upgrade nodejs version problem solved

Answer (score 2):

Only dependency is swanky itself. Can you check the package.json in the newly created project, and what happens if you run `yarn` (`npm i`) manually?

The compile command has been updated. It is now under `contract` command.
So the correct way to call it is:
`swanky contract compile flipper`